# Flutter - Target file "–flavor" not found

Tags: flutter, android-flavors

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.tengio.com/blog/multiple-firebase-environments-with-flutter/) to manage different Firebase environments.

However, when trying to run the app with a specific flavor, it doesn't work.

I do :

```
flutter run -flavor dev
```

or:

```
flutter run --flavor dev
```

But I get this error message:

> Target file "–flavor" not found.

Here is the relevant part of my

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
  dev {
    dimension "default"
    applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
  }
  tst {
    dimension "default"
    applicationIdSuffix ".tst"
  }
  prd {
    dimension "default"
  }
}
```

Sadly, I cannot find anything related to my issue on the internet.

EDIT: I don't know what kind of black magic it is, but after doing

```
flutter run -h
```

Then

```
flutter run --flavor dev
```

It worked... Time to go to sleep

Comment: Have you added this to your `build.gradle` located in `android\app\src`?

Comment: I have the same problem and i'm not able to understand what is going on. I tried "flutter run -h" but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting the error initially is that you're running `flutter run -flavor dev` - flavor needs to be **--flavor**. On the other hand, running `flutter run -h` unlikely helps since it just prints out the usage information for `flutter run`. Setting up flavors in Android, the config should be set in the Android build's app/build.gradle as mentioned in this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors#using-flavors-in-android). Separate [steps](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors#creating-flavors-in-ios) are needed if you'd like to configure one for iOS as well.